# ComboBox изменить цвет при наведении на него

Tags: css, javafx

Как мне при наведении на CheckBox изменить цвет его фона на черный, а цвет текста на белый (т.е. наоборот), тоже самое проделать с его каждой строкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 .combo-box{
       -fx-text-fill:black;
       -fx-background-color:white;
}
 .combo-box:hover{
       -fx-text-fill:white;
       -fx-background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: судя по заголовку и "с его каждой строкой" я думаю автор имел ввиду все таки ComboBox, а не CheckBox

Answer (score 2):

```
.combo-box:hover .list-cell, .combo-box:hover .arrow-button {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Но в этом случае при переводе мыши из ComboBox на элементы списка, сам ComboBox будет возвращать свой цвет.

> Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на каждую строчку ComboBox оно тоже меняло свой цвет

Как сделать это с помощью CSS я не нашел, но есть программный вариант обхода:

```
public static final String STYLE = "-fx-background-color: black;";

...

primaryStage.addEventHandler(ComboBox.ON_SHOWING, new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        if ( event.getTarget() instanceof ComboBox ) {
            ComboBox control = (ComboBox) event.getTarget();
            control.setStyle(STYLE);
        }
    }
});
primaryStage.addEventHandler(ComboBox.ON_HIDDEN, new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        if ( event.getTarget() instanceof ComboBox ) {
            ComboBox control = (ComboBox) event.getTarget();

            // если метод setStyle более нигде не используется 
            //contorl.setStyle("");

            // если метод setStyle может быть использован где либо, тогда удаляем только наши данные
            String oldStyle = control.getStyle();
            control.setStyle(oldStyle.replaceAll(STYLE, ""));
        }
    }
});
```

Не обязательно применять данные обработчики именно на primaryStage (см. по ситуации).

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на каждую строчку ComboBox оно тоже меняло свой цвет